# Close download bar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write a test. Somewhere in my test, I download a file but then need to click on a button under the download bar which appears at the bottom of the chrome browser page. I search a lot but the only solution was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476288/how-to-close-download-banner-with-chrome-webdriver) which is not my case as I don't have a scroll.

I also use:

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+ "j").build().perform();
action.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(500);        
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driverChrome.getWindowHandles());
driverChrome.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
Thread.sleep(500);
driverChrome.close();
driverChrome.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
Thread.sleep(500);
```

but it doesn't open the download page.

Anyway that I can close the download bar?

Answer (score 1):

This method did not work for me either, but I developed a workaround. I do any download test in a new window, then close the download window, the original window does not have the download bar. It must be a new window, if you do a new tab it will transfer over, to get this I use JavaScript. Switch to the new window, run download test and then switch to the original window when done.

```
string javascript = $"$(window.open('', '_blank', 'location=yes'))";

((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript(javascript); //create new window

Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles.Last())); //switch to new window

//do download test here

Driver.Close(); //close created window

Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles.First()); //back to original window with no download bar
```